# How can I combine same name of prometheus time series with different labels into one metric?

Tags: prometheus, promql

In new version, i added some labels, the series have labels:

> sentbps{
> job: "anp",
> site: "site5",
> instance: "hb_ip:9139",
> src: "node1",
> dst: "node6",
> linkid: "d1096312-8c0b-353c-20cd-e416d3ccef1f",
> dstip: "10.254.144.1",
> srcip: "10.254.144.4"
> }

previous version, the labels are:

> sentbps{
> job: "anp",
> site: "site5",
> instance: "hb_ip:9139",
> src: "node1",
> dst: "node6"
> }

so, how can i combine the two "same" metric, by shared label(site="site5",src="ndoe1", dst="node6"),
or ignore additional label(linkid,dstip,srcip).

in prometheus graph, they appears as two lines.

thks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply aggregate them. The aggregation function is not of importance here, aas you only have one line at a time, so it makes no difference of you `sum` them up or calculate an `avg`.

```
sum by (job, site, instance, src, dst) (sentbps{})
```

using the `by` clause keeps the mentioned labels but the rest (like `dstip`) are just summed up (though in your case I guess there is only one combination of `dstIp` and `dst`, they will still removed)